AWS Cognito user pools cant load in amazon console
This is a very strange issue which has been bothering me this afternoon...
I have created a user pool in amazon web services. But now. when I log in and want to browse created user pool, it loads forever and I always get timeout and my user pools don't show. I tried diferent browsers, it doesnt work in any, but when I try from my VM, it works. I dont have any specific setup or vpn or a software installed. I cant get my head around it. Again, this is not a temporary issue as it works from my VM but not from my pc.
Anyone has any ideas? Appreciate any suggestions!

Cleared cache, cleared cookies. reset chromes settings to default, restarted pc couple of times.
I would expect it to show my user pools as it does when logged in from other PC (VM).
